# $merge is saving only one document not all the fetched document: mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is my query

```
 db.orders.aggregate([
                {
                '$match': {
                         'date': ISODate("2020-02-11T18:30:00Z")
                }},
                {
                '$unwind': {
                        'path': '$orders',
                 }}, 
                {
                 $lookup:
                   {
                        from: 'retailprice',
                        let: { productCode: '$orders.productCode' },
                        pipeline: [
                        {
                                $match: {
                                frequency: 'FR',
                                $expr: {
                                        $eq: ["$productCode", "$$productCode"]
                                     }
                                  }
                        }
                        ], as: 'retailprices'
                    }
                },
                { '$unwind': '$retailprice' },
              {
                $lookup:
                     {
                        from: 'discounts',
                        let: { productCode: '$orders.productCode' },
                        pipeline: [
                        {
                                $match: {
                                frequency: 'FR',
                                $expr: {
                                        $eq: ["$productCode", "$$productCode"]
                                }
                             }
                        }
                        ], as: 'discounts'
                }},
                { '$unwind': '$discounts' },
                {
                        '$project':{
                        'productCode':'$orders.productCode' ,
                        'vendorId':'$vendorId',
                        'dealerId':'$dealerId',
                        'quantity':'$orders.quantity'
                        } 
                },{'$merge':'test'}
        ]).pretty()
```

So the output of this query without `{'$merge':'test'}` is :

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e3a710af2657521e8c5668a"),
    "productCode" : "TCE1",
    "vendorId" : ObjectId("5e3d05ba964d0e06c4bb0f07"),
    "dealerId" : ObjectId("5e1d82156a67173cb877f67d"),
    "quantity" : 30,
   }
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e3a710af2657521e8c5668a"),
    "productCode" : "ECE1",
    "vendorId" : ObjectId("5e3d05ba964d0e06c4bb0f07"),
    "dealerId" : ObjectId("5e1d82156a67173cb877f67d"),
    "quantity" : 67,
   }
```

But when I use `{'$merge':'test'}` to save the output into the new collection it saves only one document which is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e3a710af2657521e8c5668a"),
    "dealerId" : ObjectId("5e1d82156a67173cb877f67d"),
    "productCode" : "ECE1",
    "quantity" : 67,
    "vendorId" : ObjectId("5e3d05ba964d0e06c4bb0f07")
 }
```

Now why is this? I assume its because `"_id":ObjectId("5e3a710af2657521e8c5668a")` is same in both the documents if the query output is checked, if that's the case how it can be tackled. How can both the documents be saved using `$merge`, I do not want to use `$out` as it replaces the whole document whenever the query is run again or rather how can i save all the fetched documents into a new collection

Comment: add `{$project: {_id:0}}` to remove the `_id` field before the merge stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assuming right when thinking about an _id issue : the $unwind stage produce one document per array element, all with the same _id (which is, as other fields, replicated from the original document)
And the trick is... very simple! Add "_id":0 to your $project stage. Then mongodb will [create a new _id](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#id-field-generation) on $merge insertion.

```
...
        {
                '$project':{
                '_id':0,
                'productCode':'$orders.productCode' ,
                'vendorId':'$vendorId',
                'dealerId':'$dealerId',
                'quantity':'$orders.quantity'
                } 
        },
...
```

But notice that with that way, mongoDB will **allways** create new insertion, and never update an existing one. If you need more precise behaviour, check the [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#syntax) optionnal properties

Comment: @-matthPen this resolved my current issue and yes i do need more precise behaviour of $merge what if i have another query and its output is `totalAmount:342.2` and i want to save this into above mentioned `test` collection, now this query which is generating `totalAmount` already is checking all the required fields like vendorId,date,dealerId etc.So can i save this `totalAmount` in `test` collection against the existing documents not a new document,though i did try { $merge: { into: "myOutput", on: "_id", whenMatched: "replace", whenNotMatched: "insert" } } this but i couldn't make it work

Comment: please provide sample data and your new query

Comment: @- – matthPen it took me some time but i was able to resolve it , thanks to your answer that helped in resolving the other issue too